# What does an asterisk mean in a Python function signature in documentation?

Tags: python, subprocess

*EDIT: This was closed as a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters), however as I noted in the OP the usage here clearly not related to list/dictionary unpacking, this is a distinct question.*

While reading the docs for the `subprocess` module I noticed that a number of methods take an `*` argument. For example, [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```py
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
               capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None,
               check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, 
               universal_newlines=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
```

I initially interpreted that to mean the preceding positional argument (`args` in this case) could be repeated any number of times before key-word arguments, but I don't think that is correct. For example, the `subprocess.Popen` constructor also has an argument referred to only as `*`, but in that case it follows a keyword argument (`pass_fds`).

```py
subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=- 1, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
                 preexec_fn=None, close_fds=True, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None,
                 universal_newlines=None, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0,
                 restore_signals=True, start_new_session=False, pass_fds=(), *, group=None,
                 extra_groups=None, user=None, umask=- 1, encoding=None, errors=None,
                 text=None, pipesize=- 1)
```

Attempting to search for this just returns results about using `*args` and `**kwargs`, and looking at the source code has not elucidated anything to me.

Comment: keyword-only args

Comment: @Aaron as you note the mysterious `*` does not appear in the actual function signature for `subprocess.run`, but it *does* appear in the signature for `subprocess.Popen.__init__`, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/subprocess.py#L758) , so presumably it is valid.

Comment: As I revisit this I am realizing that @acushner's answer is correct, this is explained in detail in [PEP 3102](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/)

Comment: @Nick evidently I was wrong. I will delete my comments to prevent confusion. I had never encountered this notation outside of documentation, and was unaware it was legal python syntax.

Comment: No problem @Aaron! Thanks for taking the time to look at my question!